# Get gridview row values when checkbox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with checkboxes to select the row. On checking the checkbox I need to get the row values into a string/session. Below is the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"    
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"  OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"  OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  Width ="1000px" class="grid" AllowPaging="True" PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First" PagerSettings-LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="2" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="5">
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="2"  FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"/> 
    <Columns>   
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
               <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>   
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Connection">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_conn" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Connection") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>   

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Usrid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Usrid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:TextBox>   
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_pwd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Password") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pwd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>   
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Connection Name">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_conName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Connection_Name") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_conName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Connection_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>   
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>   


           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server"  Text=" Edit" class=" btnEdit"  CommandName="Edit" />   
            </ItemTemplate>   
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" class=" btnEdit" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>   
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" class=" btnEdit" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>   
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>  
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" class=" btnDelete" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')" />   
            </ItemTemplate>   

        </asp:TemplateField> 
    </Columns>   
</asp:GridView>
```

There is a button below the grid. on click of the button I need to get the values.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow item in GdvTestData.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (item.FindControl("CheckBox3") as CheckBox);
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            string conn = item.Cells[1].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

But am getting null value for `string conn = item.Cells[1].Text;`
where am I going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid contains the different row type like `header row` , `data row` and `footer row`. You need to get content from the data row only then please check the row type first if it is a data row then try to get cell values. [GridViewRow.RowType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach(GridViewRow item in GdvTestData.Rows) {
// check row is datarow
 if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    CheckBox chk = (item.FindControl("CheckBox3") as CheckBox);
    if (chk.Checked) 
    {          
       Label MyLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lbl_conn");  
       string conn = MyLabel.Text;   
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: On checking the row type also I am getting null value

Comment: And I think it should be if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

Comment: I also need only one checkbox to be selected at a time. Now I am able to select all checkboxes. (It should work like radio button inside gridview)

Comment: On checking the checkbox it doesn't fire selectedindexchange event, I want to change the selected row color

Comment: I tried with this solution but expression result is _chk = {Text = "" Checked = false} although I checked before.